# Istio. How to add Virtual Host to Envoy?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar

Using Istio EnvoyFilter https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/ I want to add new VirtualHost inside Envoy in sidecar of pods.
How to do this?

I guess I should create and apply manifest something like:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: my-filter
  namespace: default
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      run: mylabel
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: ???
    match:
      context: SIDECAR
    patch:
      operation: ADD
      value:
        ???
```

Comment: could you explain what do you mean with virtualhost?

Comment: See 17th string at https://github.com/tetratelabs/proxy-wasm-go-sdk/blob/main/examples/http_routing/envoy.yaml

Comment: use istio virtualservice object for that